# React CRA typescript eslint, build error, ReferenceError: process is not define

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, create-react-app, craco

The application stopped starting at the same place, I updated all the packages, added сrako config, the application started, but there is an error in the browser console

```
path.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at ./node_modules/path/path.js (path.js:24:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js (index.js:15:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/hooks/useVideoRecordModal/VideoCapturing/index.tsx (index.styled.ts:103:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

## **package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-router": "5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"typescript": "4.8.4",
}
"resolutions": {
   "//": "See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773",
   "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
},
```

## **.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "react-app"
  ],
  "overrides": [],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": { "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser", "ecmaVersion": "latest", "sourceType": "module" },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "react-hooks", "prettier"],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"],
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".native.js"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "./src/"]
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/display-name": "off",
    "default-param-last": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-useless-fragment": [2, { "allowExpressions": true }],

    "react/function-component-definition": [
      2,
      {
        "namedComponents": "arrow-function",
        "unnamedComponents": "arrow-function"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": "off",
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "react/require-default-props": 0,
    "consistent-return": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": [0, { "allow": ["_bar"] }],

    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", { "devDependencies": true }],

    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      "warn",
      {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    ],
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
    ],
    "max-len": [
      "warn",
      {
        "code": 120,
        "tabWidth": 2,
        "comments": 120,
        "ignoreComments": false,
        "ignoreTrailingComments": true,
        "ignoreUrls": true,
        "ignoreStrings": true,
        "ignoreTemplateLiterals": true,
        "ignoreRegExpLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "no-param-reassign": [
      "error",
      {
        "props": true,
        "ignorePropertyModificationsFor": ["draft"]
      }
    ],
    "react/prop-types": "off"
  }
}
```

## **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src", "*.ts", "*.tsx"]
}
```

Im trying to change:

- update all packages
- add craco for building
- change version of react/eslint/typescript
- configs eslint/typescript